# Music player stops

Tags: android, audio-player

I am using my own music player app that uses a foreground service with a `android.media.MediaPlayer` with wake mode `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` to play music. The permissions `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` and `WAKE_LOCK` are declared in the manifest.

All this has worked fine for years on my Huawei device running Android 9 (API 28) but on my new Samsung Galaxy A51 running Android 10 (API 29) the music stops playing after a while. The first few songs are fine but after while the next song doesn't start playing after the end of the previous song is reached (the next song is started in `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.onCompletion()`). It's not that the app gets killed, as soon as I turn on the screen the next song starts playing.

I've tried whitelisting my app in the Android preferences "Apps/Special access/Optimize battery usage" and using `ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS`. I've read about using something like `MediaSession` to register my app as a music player and a few other StackOverflow posts describing similar issues and I've tried a few solutions but nothing is working. Maybe someone can send me in the right direction.

EDIT: This is how the `MediaPlayer` is started from the service (minified version):

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    player.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
            .build()
    );
    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    player.setOnErrorListener(this);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    play();
}

public void play() {
    player.reset();
    player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), getSong().getContentUri());
    player.prepareAsync();
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
    setVolume();
    player.start();
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
    // Go to next song.
    play();
}
```

Comment: perhaps include all your current code, enough for others to copy paste as a complete example, might give you better answers

Comment: I've read several other posts like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37834195/mediaplayer-doze-mode-wake-lock-foreground-service, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64684419/android-doze-mode-kills-foregreound-mediaplayer-service and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49098126/android-media-player-stop-playing-in-service but nothing seems to be working. Apps like Spotify seem to work fine. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try following this link it might help. Otherwise please share the code so that i can further assist you. stackoverflow.com/a/60235317/14884388

Comment: I am not trying to record anything and there is no IllegalStateException. I don't know what other code you need, I've shared the code that shows how my MediaPlayer is started.

Comment: What is your logcat saying? try to run songs on connected device and see the error on logcat when app crash